# Step num ciclo for

Tags: javascript

Quero colocar dentro de um *array*, os valores entre -20 e 30, a parte de um tamanho que é 10. O meu problema é que consigo colocar os valores, mas o tamanha do array fica com 11 valores.

```js
max=30;
min=-20;
step=10;
arr_text_y=[];

var calc = max - min;
var div = calc / step;
var value =  min + div;
arr_text_y[0] = min;
for(var i = 1; i <= step; i++)
{
    var val = arr_text_y[i-1] + div;
    var fixed = Math.round(val * 100) / 100;
    arr_text_y[i] = fixed;
}
console.log(arr_text_y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Javascript o índice de um [*array* começa a partir do *0*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessando_elementos_array), não *1*, logo o resultado do teu código está certo.

Alternativamente você pode fazer:

```js
max  = 30;
min  =-20;
step = 5;
arr_text_y = [];

for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step){
    if (arr_text_y.length == 10) // Se tiver 10 elementos, interrompe.
       break;
    arr_text_y.push(i);
}
alert(arr_text_y);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas so me vai por no array 6 elementos. Queria que tivesse os 10 elements, como o step.

Comment: @akm Só diminuir o `step` para *5*. =)

Comment: Mas assim também tem 11 elementos.

Comment: Sim, mas o ultimo valor, 30, não aparece no array. Entre -20 e 30. Esses dois valores tem de aparecer no array, como minimo e máximo.

Comment: @akm Se temos como mínimo `-20`, máximo `+30`, e o *step* `5`, temos o **resultado**: *-20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30*, você deve considerar que o índice **começa em 0** no JS, para fazer isso o que você quer fazer, você terá que "**sacrificar**" um elemento da *array*. =)

Comment: @akm Dependendo do que você quer fazer, talvez hajam outras maneiras.

Answer (score 1):

Voce ta cometendo muito erro na sua função.

```
1º- 30 -(-20) = 50. se sua ideia era que desse 10 voce deve colocar min=20, ou max+min(sendo 30+(-20)=10).

2º- Se voce quer que passe 10x no for seria (i=1; i<=10; i++)

3º- var fixed = Math.round(val * 100) / 100; Sempre será fixed=val.Creio que seu intuito seria Math.round(val / 100) * 100; - para arredondar.
```

Answer (score 0):

A questão aqui é relativamente simples pegando no teu código, que está bom, mas se queres que sejam só 10 passos (como é definido na variável `steps`) basta uma das seguintes pequena alteração, que em minha opinião não tem nada a ver com os índices, que isso esta bem definido:

```js
max=30;
min=-20;
step=10;
arr_text_y=[];

var calc = max - min;
var div = calc / step;
var value =  min + div; //não está a ser utilizado.
arr_text_y[0] = min;
for(var i = 1; i < step; i++) //Tirar o igual para ele só passar no ciclo 9 vezes, vai assim ignorar o último valor.
                              //Para retirar o primeiro em vez do último, poderá utilizar a variável que não está a ser utilizada assim: arr_text_y[0] = value;
{
    var val = arr_text_y[i-1] + div;
    var fixed = Math.round(val * 100) / 100;
    arr_text_y[i] = fixed;
}
console.log(arr_text_y);
```

Ou, para mim o mais correcto seria:

```js
max=30;
min=-20;
step=10;
arr_text_y=[];

var calc = max - min;
var div = calc / (step-1); //Para que sejam mesmo os valores entre os -20 e os 30 inclusive, em 10 passos. 
var value =  min + div; //não está a ser utilizado.
arr_text_y[0] = min;
for(var i = 1; i <= step; i++)
{
    var val = arr_text_y[i-1] + div;
    var fixed = Math.round(val * 100) / 100;
    arr_text_y[i] = fixed;
}
console.log(arr_text_y);
```

Isto é devido a um pequeno erro cometido por todos nós inconscientemente, que esquecermo-nos que se queremos ir do 1 ao 10, em 10 passos,  que temos de dar 9 passos, se considerarmos o mínimo, o nosso primeiro número:

```
calc = max - min = 10 - 1 = 9
```

.